# Apple-app-site-association file won't download

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have uploaded my apple-app-site-association file to the root of my HTTPS web server After, I have added my Associated Domains in the xcode .I have followed apple universal link tutorial.

[SWC] ### Denying redirect to 'https://examplecustomdomain.com/apple-app-site-association/' (original 'https://examplecustomdomain.com/apple-app-site-association')

I have checked my device logs and I have seen error like above

Answer (score 6):

Ran into this same issue recently trying to implement Universal Links functionality. fbeeper gave a good response that helped me validate that there was indeed a redirect occurring.

However, it didn't help me in determining how to resolve the redirect issue. So for those like myself that are working with a Ruby on Rails based backend, here's an example of how to serve that pesky apple-app-site-association file in a way that meets all of Apple's requirements:

- Place your `apple_app_site_association` json file in the `public` folder
- In your `config/routes.rb` file, add a line like:

`get '/apple-app-site-association' => 'home#apple_app_site_association'`

- Then in the relevant controller file (home_controller in this example), define your method:

  `def apple_app_site_association 
    association_json = File.read(Rails.public_path + "apple-app-site-association")
    render :json => association_json, :content_type => "application/pkcs7-mime"
  end`

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting an awfully similar error:

```
[SWC] ### Denying redirect to 'https://www.<domain>/apple-app-site-association' (original 'https://<domain>/apple-app-site-association')
```

Quoting Apple's documentation:

> - The file must be hosted on an https:// site with a valid certificate (for example, Safari must not issue a certificate warning when viewing the site).
> - The file must not use any redirects.
> - The file must have the MIME type application/pkcs7-mime.

My guess here is that -for both of us,- the file can be obtained, but it is *after* being redirected. The OS won't follow that redirection even if it is under the same domain; And, apparently, complains about it on the log.

Run `curl -i https://<domain>/apple-app-site-association` and you might see `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`, with `Location: https://www.<domain>/apple-app-site-association` (or similar).

Answer (score 1):

It works only on https server.

Steps:

1) Create a file like ***apple_app_site_association*** without any extension under public directory of rails application with following contents

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "<TEAM_DEVELOPER_ID>.<BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER>",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

2) routes.rb

```
get '/apple-app-site-association', to: 'pages#apple_app_site_association'
```

3) pages_controller.rb

```
def apple_app_site_association 
   association_json = File.read(Rails.public_path + "apple_app_site_association")
   render :json => association_json, :content_type => "application/json"
end
```

For example you check

http://18.216.158.101/apple-app-site-association

To test you can create an app on heroku.