# Getting apple-app-site-association, heroku, and Route 53 to play nice

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ios-universal-links

My web app is hosted on heroku (Ruby on Rails). I use Amazon Route 53 for DNS. I have followed the Heroku docs for configuring Automated Certificate Management so my app can serve HTTPS. I have tested this through a web browser and I am able to access the site fine with HTTPS. I'm relatively certain that a) routing to heroku is working 2) https is working.

Here is where the difficult comes in. I am trying to get my app association file to work with my mobile app. I am able to pull up the file by going to my domain: https://www.example.com/apple-app-site-association.

My ruby app serves up the file in the manner suggested by this SO post:https://stackoverflow.com/a/35588346/5357940.

I have validated that the link is working without redirects with redirectcheck.com. This shows the content type is correct and that there are no redirects happening.

https://www.example.com/apple-app-site-association

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 28 Mar 2017 23:29:50 GMT
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Request-Id: 21fd0610-2797-4c83-81ec-d54616086036
X-Runtime: 0.184758
Via: 1.1 vegur

When I run the apple validator, all the tests pass except for the "Link To Application" test. The error returned is:

App Name Domain
Link http://www.example.com/testlink
Bundle Id com.example.app
Universal false
Error cannot fetch app site association

I have read through all the other SO question on this topic, but can't find one that addresses the specific problem I am having.

p.s. I have replaced the name of the app with domain.

Comment: p.s. I am NOT signing the file as suggested in the following WWDC: http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/509

Answer (score 0):

After much futzing, I found that everything was actually working despite apple's validation tool telling me otherwise. Since I did not have my app with the appropriate site applinks registered, I could not test in the app. It appears this is because Apple's validator apparently caches site association files. Even though I was changing my site file, apple kept saying it was not readable when in fact it was.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue that i found in my case is that i should add ALL subdomains for Domain association capability:[image]